# Возникает ошибка при импорте файла из папки, которая лежит в одной папке со скриптом Python

Tags: python

структура проекта:

```
папка:
   файл2
   файл3
файл1
```

Возникает ошибка при импорте файла из папки, которая лежит в одной папке со скриптом Python.

1. Создал папку рядом с запускаемым скриптом.
2. Создал пару скриптов в этой папке.
3. Один из скриптов в этой папке импортирует рядом лежащий файл.
4. В запускаемом скрипте (`файл1`), импортировал `файл2`.
5. Возникает ошибка

   > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

   что значмт файл2 не может импортировать рядом файл3

В файл2 прописано:

```
from папка.файл3 import function
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Так как файл3 и файл2 лежат в одной папке, надо писать

```
from файл3 import function
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от того, какой скрипт (файл) вы запускаете.

Команда

```
from папка.файл3 import function
```

(в файле `файл2.py`) работает правильно, когда вы запускаете вашу программу с файла `файл1.py`.

Но когда вы хотите запускать скрипт с файла `файл2.py`, нужно эту команду изменить на

```
from файл3 import function
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Файл `файл1.py` находится в той же самой папке как папка `папка`, значит, он «видит» эту папку, но не (прямо) модуль `файл3.py`.

Подобным образом файл `файл2.py` «видит» модуль `файл3.py`, но не папку `папка`.

Comment: PyCharm от JetBrains ругается на это и возникает ошибка, что файл3 не найден

Comment: @N.Maxim, я изменил мой ответ, чтобы всё было понятно. Для меня это работает и в PyCharm. Когда у вас это не работает, напишите, какой версией Питона вы пользуетесь (в Питон консоли PyCharm напишите `import sys; sys.version`).